# Getting rid of account sign-ups in E-comm site?

Tags: accounts

I'm entertaining the idea of completely removing the option to create an account on my E-commerce store(pop culture collectibles store). At current, only about 3-5% of customers ever bother to create an account, and when they do they don't really utilise any of it's features at all, like the complete address book to store multiple address, ability to create and share wishlists to social media sites etc plus access to invoices etc

Though no one uses it.

I was wondering peoples thoughts on whether or not they would be bothered to shop online at a store that doesn't have an account option? Do you think it would drive down repeat customers having to manually enter their address each time they place an order?

All invoices are sent in PDF VIA email, as well as a link to their invoice they can access online at anytime. So there's no problems there with ever having access to anything like that at any time.

I'm looking to just really dumb down my site with 100% focus on making the user shopping experience as simple and easy as possible with no resistance in any form what so ever.

I would obviously have an option to subscribe to an email newsletter, but that would be it.

Do you think this is going too far? Do you prefer account access and address storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there is already an option to order without creating an account?
What would be the benefit of removing the account possibility?
Unless you really have a very limited number of repeating customers, keep both options, make the process of creating an account for those that do want it as easy as possible and promote the benefits of actually having an account.

From personal experience, if I'm ordering for the first time or I'm sure I'll only order once from a particular site, I don't want all the fuss of having to create an account and getting a bunch of newsletters I don't even want.
Once I'm convinced I'll order more frequently, yes I like the possibility to keep a wish list, multiple delivery addresses, billing info, ...

Comment: Thanks. Yes there's the option to create an account should the customer wish to, though i don't really get any repeat customers. But I think you're right, it should still be an option to have it, but i will try to keep it very simple. Thank you for your reply